# Random number of jasmine tests fail when run together, but they pass individually?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have around 450 assorted `specs` written in `Jasmine` (`async` & `sync`) in my codebase. `Karma` is the test runner which I use for running the tests on a headless chrome browser. Whenever I run the tests as a whole, a few of the tests fail because of the following error: 
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` When I run these failing tests individually, they pass without any problem.

On every test run (all tests), the failing tests are different i.e., sometimes, `async` test A and B fails in the first test run and in the second test run, `async` test C and D fails.

I clearly see that the problem is always with the Async tests, but how do I fix this issue properly. I tried increasing the `timeout` in the configuration, it does work sometimes but the tests start failing again with the same `async timeout error` after a few runs. Currently, I have the timeout at `160000 ms`.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you connecting to an actually server? Are you aware about its configurations? It might be that the server is incapable of handling so many requests, or (if its a third party) [throttling](https://www.progress.com/blogs/how-to-rate-limit-an-api-query-throttling-made-easy) your requests.